# How to generate a random set of integers from a specified range excluding one integer in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

For Eg: I want 127 random integers from (1:127) but it shouldn't contain the integer 64.

Can someone help me.

Comment: Just keep generating random numbers until you get one that isn't 64

Comment: wouldn't that be like a looping ? I would like to get these numbers in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not generate values between 1:126 and if it's 64 or more, add one?

I'll not write your code (as I can't remember Matlab syntax), but something like this pseudo-C# code will do what you want:

```
var value = nextRandom(1, 126);
if ( value >= 64 )
    value++;
return value;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the conversion of [Wai Ha Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051782/5698672) into MATLAB's syntax.

```
A = randi([1 126], 127, 1); %Generating 127 random integers from 1 to 126
A(A>=64)= A(A>=64)+1;       %Adding 1 to the integers from 64 to 126
```